# ¿Cómo puedo quitar columnheaders en un export a EXCEL?

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

Lo que trato de hacer es que se retire el `columnheader` del `export` en el subreporte en `excel`, solo quiero que aparezcan los datos, más no la banda superior.

ya intenté lo siguiente y no funciona.

```
.addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.3", "columnHeader")    
.addProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2", "columnHeader")
```

Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacerlo.